# Can I build 2 IServiceProvider and they work together (.net core )

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
    IServiceCollection serviceConfiguration = ConfigureServices();       
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceConfiguration.BuildServiceProvider();
    IBusControl busControl = CreateServiceBus(serviceProvider);

    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<IBusControl>(busControl);      
    IServiceProvider serviceBus = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

is it possible to do it like this, i need it because CreateServiceBus using the first IServiceProvider, it using it by dependancy injection this why i need 2 IServiceProvider because after this i want register busControl as IBusControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a factory method and warm it up in `Startup.cs`.

```
services.AddSingleton<IBusControl>(provider => CreateServiceBus(provider));
```

and then "warm" it up in `Configure` method

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app, IBusControl bus)
{
}
```

or

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app, IBusControl bus)
{
    app.Services.GetRequriedService<IBusControl>();
}
```